# withFragmentManager (android.app.FragmentManager) in Builder cannot be applied to (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)

Tags: android, migration, androidx, android-studio-3.0, fragmentmanager

I'm trying migrate to androidX  and  make a file chooser class in my Fragment this is my code:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
public class FragmentControl extends Fragment {
    private TextView list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);

        list = view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);

        final StorageChooser chooser = new StorageChooser.Builder()
                // Specify context of the dialog
                .withActivity(getActivity())
                .withFragmentManager(getFragmentManager())
                .withMemoryBar(true)
                .allowCustomPath(true)
                // Define the mode as the FILE CHOOSER
                .setType(StorageChooser.FILE_PICKER)
                .build();
        chooser.setOnSelectListener(new StorageChooser.OnSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelect(String path) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The selected path is : " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        chooser.show();

        return view;
    }
```

but [FragmentManager was deprecated in API level 28.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager)
my problem is how I Use it in Androidx? and how to replace getFragmentManager()?

the error is:

> withFragmentManager (android.app.FragmentManager) in Builder cannot be applied to (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)

how I solve this problem thanks

Comment: Looks like there is an [issue](https://github.com/codekidX/storage-chooser/issues/107)

Answer (score 1):

That method only supports the legacy `FragmentManager`

...but version 3.0 will support that; see the [issue tracker](https://github.com/codekidX/storage-chooser/issues/107).

Comment: do you know better chooser class for Fragment thanks